# Правильно ли будет сказать следующее выражение

Tags: грамотная-речь

скажите, пожалуйста, не будет ли ошибки, если сказать: "мы молили судьбу, чтоб нас снова свёл бог"?

Comment: Что именно вызывает сомнение?

Comment: «Если сказать..» Вы не в эфире вопрос задали. Извольте не игнорировать прописные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, это *будет* стилистической ошибкой (судьбу просят решить что-то за бога). Бог неподвластен "судьбе": даже этимологически судьба - "суд божий". В предложенном высказывании можно оставить что-то одно ("судьбу, чтобы она нас свела", или бога в том же контексте, если говорит верующий), либо говорить о "молении бога" в отношении своей судьбы - тогда не будет противоречия. Без этого высказывание как минимум выдаёт неверие говорящего, "всуе поминающего бога", не отличая его от "судьбы" (приводя как синоним) или в мыслях своих подчиняя его "судьбе".